# Folium Choropleth Maps -- when do I need "geojson" parameter b/f .add_to(map)

Tags: python, geojson, layers, folium, choropleth

Normally, when I create a choropleth map with Folium, at the end of the `folium.Choropleth()` call, I just `.add_to(map)`:

```
folium.Choropleth().add_to(m)
```

I've been trying to create a map with multiple choropleth FeatureGroups. When I do so, if I follow this procedure, I get

> AssertionError: Choropleth must be added to a Map object.

But by inserting `geojson`, I can add it to the layer without an error. So in the above code:

```
folium.Choropleth().geojson.add_to(m)
```

I don't understand what is happening. Can someone explain this to me?

The full code looks like this:

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[40, -96],tiles = None)

for group in groups:
  filter = census['Group Name'].str.contains(group,na=False)
  map_df = census[filter].groupby(['FIPS'])['PctTotPop'].sum()*100

  layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name = group, overlay = False).add_to(m)
  
  cp = folium.Choropleth(
          geo_data = counties,
          data = map_df, 
          columns = ['FIPS','ScaleTotPop'],
          key_on = 'feature.properties.FIPS',
          bins = 9,
          fill_color='OrRd',
          fill_opacity=0.8,
          line_opacity=0.2,
          nan_fill_color = 'grey',
          legend_name='Percent of county population'
          ).geojson.add_to(layer) # <- WHY geojson here?

folium.TileLayer('OpenStreetMap',overlay=True,control = False).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: I don't see any "geopandas" anywhere in the above code. You probably mean "geojson".

Comment: Dho! Thanks - edited title.