# Add extra info to the GeoJSON `features` from a Folium choropleth map with multiple feature groups

Tags: geojson, layers, folium, choropleth

When I make a single Folium choropleth map, I often add data from my data DF to the GeoJSON data, so it can be displayed with the `folium.GeoJsonTooltip()`.

My code looks like this:

```py
map_data_lookup = map_df.set_index('FIPS')

for row in cp.geojson.data['features']:
  try:
      row['properties']['PctTotPop'] = f"{(map_data_lookup.loc[row['properties']['FIPS'],'PctTotPop']):.2f}%"
  except KeyError:
      row['properties']['PctTotPop'] = 'No adherents'

folium.GeoJsonTooltip(['NAME','PctTotPop'],aliases=['County:','Pop in Cong:']).add_to(cp.geojson)
```

Recently, I've been trying to create a map with multiple choropleth layers.

When I use the above code block in a multi-choropleth / layer map, I get an

> AttributeError: GeoJson object has no attribute 'geojson'.

The full code looks like this that generates the error:

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[40, -96],tiles = None)

for group in groups:
  filter = census['Group Name'].str.contains(group,na=False)
  map_df = census[filter].groupby(['FIPS'])['PctTotPop'].sum()*100

  layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name = group, overlay = False).add_to(m)
  
  cp = folium.Choropleth(
          geo_data = counties,
          data = map_df, 
          columns = ['FIPS','ScaleTotPop'],
          key_on = 'feature.properties.FIPS',
          bins = 9,
          fill_color='OrRd',
          fill_opacity=0.8,
          line_opacity=0.2,
          nan_fill_color = 'grey',
          legend_name='Percent of county population'
          ).geojson.add_to(layer) # <- why is geojson required here?

  map_data_lookup = map_df.set_index('FIPS')

  for row in cp.geojson.data['features']:
    try:
        row['properties']['PctTotPop'] = f"{(map_data_lookup.loc[row['properties']['FIPS'],'PctTotPop']):.2f}%"
    except KeyError:
        row['properties']['PctTotPop'] = 'No adherents'

  folium.GeoJsonTooltip(['NAME','PctTotPop'],aliases=['County:','Pop in Cong:']
                        ).add_to(cp.geojson)

folium.TileLayer('OpenStreetMap',overlay=True,control = False).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

I think there's something going on with the GeoJSON data -- to add the choropleth map data to the layer, I need to add `geojson` to the `.add_to(layer)` statement. But I don't understand what's happening -- that's the question I ask [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458035/folium-choropleth-maps-when-do-i-need-geopandas-parameter-b-f-add-tomap).